# undefined reference when using template function

Tags: c++, templates

The following code is simplified to show only the problem

```
template <unsigned bits_count, typename ut_t = unsigned short, typename st_t = short, typename udt_t = unsigned, typename sdt_t = int>
struct int_t
{
    typedef ut_t     ut;

    ut comp[bits_count / (sizeof(ut) * 8)];
};

template<typename ot, typename it>
inline ot& mathx_int_from_t_to_niv(const it& value, ot& result)
{
    typedef typename it::ut ut;

    result = ot(0);

    if (sizeof(ot) <= sizeof(ut)) return result = ot(value.comp[0]);

    return result = *(ot*)value.comp;
}

template <typename ot, typename it>
ot numeric_cast(const it& value);

template<unsigned bits_count, typename ut_t, typename st_t, typename udt_t, typename sdt_t>
inline int numeric_cast(const int_t<bits_count, ut_t, st_t, udt_t, sdt_t>& value)
{
    typedef int_t<bits_count, ut_t, st_t, udt_t, sdt_t> it;
    int result;

    return mathx_int_from_t_to_niv<int, it>(value, result);
}

typedef int_t<128>  int128;

int main()
{
    int128 s = { { 0 } };
    s.comp[0] = -1;

    int t = numeric_cast<int>(s);
}
```

The above code compile with error `undefined reference to 'int numeric_cast<int, int_t<128u, unsigned short, short, unsigned int, int> >(int_t<128u, unsigned short, short, unsigned int, int> const&)'`

I don't understand why gcc generate this error, when i explicitly write the partial specialization for `numeric_cast` it says it's not allowed and when i provide an overload it says undefined reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you haven't provided a definition for this function template:

```
template <typename ot, typename it>
ot numeric_cast(const it& value);
```

Which gets picked by overload resolution when you do:

```
int t = numeric_cast<int>(s);
```

And this overload gets picked because the second `numeric_cast` template expects a non-type argument as its first template argument, so `numeric_cast<int>` is not a valid attempt to instantiate it.

Comment: The declaration should have multiple definition for several types. How can i solve this problem without explicitly provide implementation for this declaration?

Comment: @Muhammadalaa: I'm not sure I understand. Why are you providing an explicit `int` argument to `numeric_cast<>` (i.e `numeric_cast<int>`)?

Comment: `numeric_cast` should convert between source and target types the source is native type or `int_t` and the target is `int_t` or native type, FYI there is also `uint_t` and `float_t` that's why the declaration for `numeric_cast` is generic.

Comment: @Muhammadalaa: But even if partial specialization of function templates were allowed, how could you make the second template a specialization of the first one, considering that the first one always *expects* one template argument to be specified explicitly, and the second one *requires* that no template argument is specified explicitly?

Comment: My previous declaration for `numeric_cast` was `template<typename it> struct numeric_cast { template<typename ot> operator ot(); };` but it's usage cause conflict because the input parameter is the source type not the target, so i tried to simplify it with function but clearly i didn't give it enough planning.

Comment: @Muhammadalaa: Yes, perhaps you have to give a deeper thought to the design. It seems to me you are trying to make two things "fit into one", but those two things have different expectations on their template arguments, and this non-uniformity makes it impossible to treat them as a specialization of the same primary template